# Secure write access to system file (/etc/aliases)

Tags: permissions, unix

I'm writing a program (in Python) that needs to modify a system file, /etc/aliases in this case. The software is a web application that typically will run under a dedicated web user, ie "www", "www-data", "apache" or similar.

How should I set up access control (file permissions, file ownership and groups) to enable the program to modify /etc/aliases without opening permissions too much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way is to make `/etc/aliases` owned by the web user. There are several ways you can make this more secure; it's a matter of what threats you're concerned about and how much complexity you're prepared to add to mitigate them.

If the application is only supposed to modify some aliases, you might be able to set up your MTA to read several alias files, and make only one of them writable by your application. I don't think this will buy you much security against a security hole in the application: if an attacker adds a redirection from `webmaster` to `evil@mastermind.com`, it doesn't matter which file it's been added to. But this could be useful in combination with review mechanisms.

If you want to review or audit what the application is doing, don't give it write access to `/etc/aliases`. Instead, make it write a temporary file somewhere, then invoke a privileged program to validate this file and merge the data into `/etc/aliases` (or a dedicated file as suggested above). The privileged program, let's call it `merge-myapp-aliases`, should be executable by the web user, and setgid to a dedicated group. That is, `merge-myapp-aliases` should be owned by `root:myapp-aliases` and mode 2755 (`rwxr-sr-x`). The reason to use a group rather than a user is that even if there's a security hole in the executable, the attacker won't be able to modify the executable to inject a trojan. The job of `merge-myapp-aliases` is to validate the contents of its input (e.g. check that it's not setting aliases for system users), log its actions, and replace the alias file by a new version.

For robustnes, the dedicated alias file should be in a dedicated directory with group write permission. Make the program write the new file (`/etc/aliases.myapp/new`), then atomically move it in place (`mv /etc/aliases.myapp/new /etc/aliases.myapp/current`). That way you won't end up with an incomplete file if the program is killed midway for whatever reason.

An alternate way of pushing the changes into place, which has the advantage of automatically leaving a complete audit trail, is to have the CGI commit a file to a revision control system, and pull a trigger for another program to check out the latest revision. Most revision control systems have a way to validate commits.

If you want to restrict the alias file to this particular application, you're going to have to run the application with elevated privileges somehow. As above, you can make it setgid to a dedicated group.

Comment: Right, because of course root can still write the file even though it's owned by the web user! Duh!  :-) Good ideas for even higher security too. I'll make sure the app is flexible enough to deal with it if users want to set it up like that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what MTS you are using.  But this information is quite important.  `/etc/aliases` is considered a *Sendmail compatibility mechanism* by several MTS softwares, whose native aliasing mechanisms are more powerful, and address the very security issues that you are hitting here.  For examples:

- In qmail [the `fastforward` add-on](http://cr.yp.to/fastforward.html) handles `/etc/aliases` by plugging it into qmail's native aliasing system.  The native aliasing system, [`.qmail` files](http://qmail.org./man/man5/dot-qmail.html), allows any local user `fred@example.com` to have a *per-user* set of aliases `fred-something@example.com` defined by `.qmail-something` files in that user's home directory.  The user doesn't need access to global root-owned files, and there's no way for `fred`'s alias files to alter what `jim-something@example.com` and `sheila-something@example.com` map to.
- In Postfix one can turn on [the `recipient_delimiter` option](http://www.postfix.org./postconf.5.html#recipient_delimiter) to gain a similar mechanism, with `fred+something@example.com` aliases defined by `.forward+something` files in that user's home directory.
- In exim, [the `local_part_suffix` option](http://exim.org./exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch15.html) can be turned on, and `$local_part_suffix` will be set to `-something` whenever the `~fred/.forward` filter is run for mail addressed to `fred-something@example.com`.

The upshot of all this is that if your MTS is qmail, Postfix, or exim your WWW application just needs *one unprivileged* local user account in order to gain control over a whole set of mailboxes, and does not need either access to the system-wide alias database or any set-UID/set-GID shenanighans.  For many tasks — running mailing lists, for example, that needs mailboxes named `list-subscribe`, `list-owner`, `list-unsubscribe`, `list-handle-bounce-from-mandy-example.net-of-message-437`, and so forth — this is enough.

Depending from what your application is, it might be enough for you, too.

Comment: I'm (or rather this customer is) using sendmail, and I'm also choosing to implement this using aliases precisely because other MTS's often have compatibility mechanisms for it.

Comment: It's not the best of ideas to choose a mechanism with security issues such as the very ones that you are encountering just because there's a backwards compatibility option for it.

Comment: First you give an answer that doesn't answer the question, and then you ignore half of my comment above. Good work.

Comment: I responded to the bit that needed a response.  Obviously the idea that you've made your own bed with your design choices when you didn't necessarily have to isn't sinking in.  I tried, but [it's now time to invoke Dukhat](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dukhat-on-foolishness.html).

Comment: You still didn't read my answer, I notice. I'll repeat for clarity: The customer is using sendmail. Is this somehow difficult to grasp? Also, using aliases makes it possible for most people to use this software, no matter what MTA they are using, as an added bonus. For example me, as my local machine does *not* use sendmail. Did you read it *now*?